# Convert an ImageMoniker to a Bitmap for a Visual Studio extension

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, casting, vs-extensibility

I want to display a status animation in the Visual Studio status bar. For the animation I need a bitmap. To prevent having duplicate files I want to get that bitmap from a given ImageMoniker that I have linked in my VSCT file.

My current code looks like this:

```
private void ShowIconInStatusBar(object sender, RatingChangedEventArgs eventArgs)
{
    IntPtr hdc = new Bitmap(@"Resources\red.bmp").GetHbitmap();
    object icon = hdc;

    this.statusBar.Animation(1, ref icon);
}
```

Ideally I would use the ImageMoniker though. I imagine something like this:

```
Bitmap b = Bitmap.FromImageMoniker(this.moniker);
```

But I can't find any way to cast an ImageMoniker to an Image or a Bitmap. How would I do that? Is it even possible to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing this directly doesn't seem to work, but I found a different solution without the need for duplicate files.

```
var bitmap = new Bitmap(path).Clone(
    new Rectangle(
        new Point(xCoordinate, 0),
        new Size(16, 16)),
    System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.DontCare);
IntPtr hdc = bitmap.GetHbitmap();
```

By using `Clone` I can achieve the same functionality that I got from the `ImageMoniker` - using only one file for all images.